# ng-model is not updating the right user in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am kind of new in AngularJS, and I have a form that users can edit there form. But when user clicks update, it updates the form. BUT, the user does not update the user. Shown in the image
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5BgB.png)

> Here is my code:

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div class="people-view">
      <h2 class="name">{{people.first}}</h2>
     <h2 class="name">{{people.last}}</h2>

  <span class="title">{{people.title}}</span>

  <span class="date">{{people.date}} </span>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- the form -->

<div class="list-view">

  <form>
    <fieldset ng-disabled="inactive">

  <legend>Basic Info</legend>

<b>First Name:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="myObject.first">
  <br>
  <b>Last Name:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="myObject.last">

    <button type="button" class="edit" ng-show="inactive" ng-click="inactive = !inactive">
          Edit
        </button>

    <button type="submit" class="submit" ng-show="!inactive" ng-click="update()">Update</button>




</form>
```

> App.js

```
    var app = angular.module("Portal", ['ngRoute']);



app.controller('MyCtrl',  function($scope) {
  $scope.inactive = true;

$scope.people = {};

 $scope.myObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myObject')) || {
     first : $scope.people.first,
     last : $scope.people.last,

   };

   $scope.update = function(){
           $scope.people.first = $scope.myObject.first;
           $scope.people.last = $scope.myObject.last;

         localStorage.setItem('myObject', JSON.stringify($scope.myObject));



       };



       $scope.deletePeople = deletePeople;
         function deletePeople(id){
         var userToDelete;
          $scope.people.forEach(function(p, index){
           if(p.id == id){
              userToDelete = index;
           }
         });

         $scope.people.splice(userToDelete, 1);
         console.log($scope.people);
         }



});
```

> List of users

```
    <div class="people" ng-repeat="p in people | filter:userSearch" >

    <a href="#/people/{{ p.id }}">
    <img ng-src="{{p.img}}"/>
    <span class="name">{{p.first}} </span>
    <span class="name">{{p.last}} </span>

   <p class="title">{{p.title}} </p>
  <span class="date">{{p.date}} </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The people view section should be included under `<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">` div. So just move that line up so it's the first line of the code.

Comment: and use my ng-model as original as in myObject.first?

Comment: BTW, check updated question. to see if I did move it in the right place

Comment: You should close the div after end of form tag.

Comment: I did. No changes. should I use my ng-model as people.first or myObject.people(as in my original code)

Comment: Why don't you try that? I mean that's  how you learn right? After trying you should let us know if it did not work. :)

Comment: I did. and yes you're right. I am just double checking.

Comment: Also, no changes :/

Comment: when they click on update, it goes to the same user that is on. no changes. when the ng-model is people.first

Comment: Would you make an jsfiddle? It will be helpful to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-model in the form needs to be people.first and people.last respectively. E.g. `<b>First Name:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="people.first">
  <br>
  <b>Last Name:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="people.last">`

Comment: I did that. When applying people.first. I get a blank input field

Comment: Do I need to show you more code, in order to solve this problem?

Comment: Try comment out $scope.people = {}; from your controller.

Comment: I did. Now, when I edit the form and click on update it shows the same user that is

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nxaj8hg9/1/)

As Swailem95 said you have to move the `<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">` top and it looks like below after that.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="people-view">
        <h2 class="name">{{people.first}}</h2>
        <h2 class="name">{{people.last}}</h2>
        <span class="title">{{people.title}}</span>
        <span class="date">{{people.date}} </span>
    </div>
    <!-- the form -->
    <div class="list-view">
        <form>
          <fieldset ng-disabled="inactive">
          <legend>Basic Info</legend>
          <b>First Name:</b>
          <input type="text" ng-model="myObject.first">
          <br>
          <b>Last Name:</b>
          <input type="text" ng-model="myObject.last">
          </fieldset>
          <button type="button" class="edit" ng-show="inactive" ng-click="inactive = !inactive">
            Edit
          </button>
          <button type="submit" class="submit" ng-show="!inactive" ng-click="update()">Update</button>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, it worked. But when I put the </fieldset> after ng-disabled. It lets the form be enabled. Which I want the form to be disabled, until they click on edit button. And, I Want title to get updated as well with form. (it just gets the form updated.)

Comment: if you see the image I posted. When it says John Smith

Comment: Yes but I can't see anything related to title in your controller code

Comment: I want that to get updated as well. BUT, again when the form changes, it duplicated to all users form, the same name. For example: In John Smith page, I edit the form as "Jane Doe", and in Ben or other users form, it shows Jane Doe.

Comment: I think it's better you create a jsfiddle with your all the issues. I cannot solve all the issues with the code you posted

Comment: I just want to know why it duplicates the form to other users form as well. ?!

Comment: I am not able to guess the code which you using. So it would be helpful to put relevant code or create jsfiddle